# Create Route53 record from command line using aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, aws-cli, amazon-route53

How can I easily create an Amazon AWS Route53 from command line? It takes too long to click around in the web console.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the **hosted zone id**. List your hosted zones:

```sh
$ aws route53 list-hosted-zones
```

The output should be:

```
{
    "HostedZones": [
        {
            "Id": "/hostedzone/ZFYKW933LX916",
            "Name": "example.com.",
            "CallerReference": "C4E8C4F3-5265-4248-B324-807A4AB90ABC",
            "Config": {
                "PrivateZone": false
            },
            "ResourceRecordSetCount": 39
        },
        {
            "Id": "/hostedzone/Z6JTNNZOHT191",
            "Name": "example.net.",
            "CallerReference": "A4001EE9-C0FD-F484-9F8D-688F681EFDEF",
            "Config": {
                "PrivateZone": false
            },
            "ResourceRecordSetCount": 16
        }
    ]
}
```

Now you need to create a **change batch**:

```sh
$ aws --profile messa route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id /hostedzone/ZFYKW933LX916 --change-batch '{"Changes": [ { "Action": "UPSERT", "ResourceRecordSet": { "Name": "foobar.example.com", "Type": "A", "TTL": 3600, "ResourceRecords": [{ "Value": "11.222.33.44" }] } } ]}'
```

The output should be:

```
{
    "ChangeInfo": {
        "Id": "/change/C2T36TTVOVS7KX",
        "Status": "PENDING",
        "SubmittedAt": "2020-02-12T12:54:43.056Z"
    }
}
```